# Render file with last updated date in middlemanapp

Tags: ruby, middleman

I've got a [humans.txt](http://humanstxt.org/Standard.html) file in the root of my [middlemanapp-powered](http://middlemanapp.com) website. I'd like to be able to update the "Last update:" value in this file whenever the site gets built or rendered.

```
/* SITE */
Last update: 2014/06/24
Standards: HTML5, CSS3
Components: Modernizr, jQuery, Selectivizr, TypeKit
Software: Sublime Text
```

Is there a generic way to create an interpreted ruby file (similar to the way you can create "file-name.html.erb" or "file-name.html.haml" depending on which templating language you use)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, humans.txt.erb seems to work just fine...

```
/* SITE */
Last update: <%= DateTime.now.strftime('%F') %>
```